# Enable http DELETE header. Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: javascript, node.js

I added the Headers to allow the http Delete, But When i try to delete(click the button) i have the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5500/method. 
(Reason: missing token access-control-allow-origin in CORS header Access-Control-Allow-Headers from CORS preflight channel

```
let allowDelete = function (req, res, next) {

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,     Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
}
```

//And

```
router.options('/method', allowDelete);

router.delete('/method', functionT);
```

The request is like follow:

```
method(paramether: Paramether) {

    return new Promise<boolean>( (resolve, reject) => {
      this._http.delete<boolean>(Url, Option).subscribe( (res => {
        resolve(res);
      }));
    });
  }
```

Do you know where the problem is?

Comment: `preflight` - so, are you handling the `OPTIONS` preflight request (looks like you are)? and should you be adding `OPTIONS` to `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i am using Options. How to add the Access-Control-Allow-Methods(or What should i change at my code)?

Comment: Adding OPTIONS method is simple: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");`. Please try it.

Answer (score -1):

You need install: **npm install cors** , after install, import into app.js nodejs
**var cors = require('cors');**

You can seen: [Create Form Register using Nodejs + Vuejs](https://hoanguyenit.com/create-form-register-using-nodejs-vuejs.html)

Comment: you don't NEED to install npm cors to handle cors